# Using generated HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use my generated HTML with jQuery, whenever someone click on the button "test" the background should change to red but it doesn't work. Whenever I click the button that I generated, it can't get functions and I was wondering how can I get the "onclick" to work

```js
// generated html
$("body").append("<button onclick=\"test()\">test</button>");

// trying to use it with jquery
function test() {
  $("body").css("background", "red");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

PS: I can't use HTML

Comment: Are you get any error? Its works good

Comment: @JagjeetSingh Whenever I click the button, nothing happens like it should. There is no error though.

Comment: Remove the backslashes in front of your quotations: $("body").append("<button onclick="test()">test</button>");

Comment: Your code works. I put it into a snippet so you can run it right here on StackOverflow. Did you forget to add jQuery to your page?

Comment: It may have been a load-order problem; your existing code works fine if inserted in the document body, but can't find the `test()` function if wrapped in an onload: https://jsfiddle.net/sc1hny26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example here:

```js
// generated html
$("body").append("<button id='test'></button>");
$("#test").html('Magic');

// set background color in jquery
$("#test").click(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use **on function** for generated HTML, you can not use simple onClick() and etc. functions for added html after document has been loaded.

```
// generated HTML
$("body").append("<button class='testButton'>Test</button>");

// trying to use it with jquery
$(document).on("click",".testButton",function(){
    $("body").css("background", "red");
})
```

Comment: Why it will not work? Any specific reasons please! @DarrenSweeney

Comment: Ohh, Thanks @DarrenSweeney... Appreciated